# Email won't stay deleted (IMAP)

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S4
App: default mail app (Android or Samsung, don't know which)
Issue: I have an IMAP email account and when I delete an email and then check for new messages later, or at the scheduled sync frequency, those emails reappear in the account - they won't stay deleted.

I can't use K-9 mail as it doesn't support Exchange Server and I have an Exchange account as well. The problem account is set up as IMAIL. I don't see any options anywhere to change server settings for deleting emails on the server as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks to me that the problem is with your IMAP server configuration...

Comment: I had lots of (similar) issues with the default mail app using my IMAP account, and was glad I was able to switch to K-9. Sorry to be of no further help.

Comment: IMAP settings are fine. I've removed the account, reset the phone added it again and no luck. If it wasn't for the need for Exchange support I'd move to K9 but it isn't an option sadly

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there is an issue with the default mail app on the Samsung Galaxy phones.
I have recently switched from iPhone to Galaxy Note 3 and was really disappointed with the mail app not properly deleting emails from the server using imap. I know what I am doing and have it successfully working on other DROID and ios devices.
My work - around is to not use the trash can icon to delete mail but instead to use the move icon and choose to move the mail to the INBOX.trash folder.
Or you could just use Maildroid as there is much more control over what you want to do. 
I am back on the default mail app now and happy with my work - around as the samsung email app works best with the Galaxy Gear smart watch.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem silly to ask, but is your **auto-sync** to gmail setting on? Assuming your email's IMAP settings are correct, then the issue is with your phone. In the case of the default email android client, you need to have auto-sync on for each added email account. Once that is checked on, your emails on the server will reflect any changes made on the phone.